# How to store token in Firebase and use it in Gmail API?

Tags: node.js, firebase, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions

I created Cloud function using NodeJS and Gmail API. Since Gmail API requires OAuth2.0, the access token must be stored in the database(Firebase). Also, I created Firebase database. Here is the code:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
databaseURL: 'https://chatapptest-389209-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/' };

admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
databaseURL: firebaseConfig.databaseURL });

async function loadSavedCredentialsIfExist() {
try {
  const snapshot = await admin.database().ref(FIREBASE_TOKEN_PATH).once('value');
  const credentials = snapshot.val();
  if (!credentials) {
    return null;
  }
  return google.auth.fromJSON(credentials);
} catch (err) {
  return null;
}}

async function saveCredentials(client) {
const content = await fs.readFile(CREDENTIALS_PATH);
const keys = JSON.parse(content);
const key = keys.installed || keys.web;
const credentials = {
  type: 'authorized_user',
  client_id: key.client_id,
  client_secret: key.client_secret,
  refresh_token: client.credentials.refresh_token,
};
await admin.database().ref(FIREBASE_TOKEN_PATH).set(credentials); }

async function authorize() {
let client = await loadSavedCredentialsIfExist();
if (client) {
  return client;
}
client = await authenticate({
  scopes: SCOPES,
  keyfilePath: CREDENTIALS_PATH,
});
if (client.credentials) {
  await saveCredentials(client);
}
return client; }
```

These functions are for OAuth2.0. The problem is that it won't write my data to Firebase and I can't get the client to call Gmail API. I don't know where i'm going wrong?